# Tensor product of Pauli strings?

Tags: pauli-gates, linear-algebra, pauli-group

We define
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{4^l} P_i \otimes P_i,
\sum_{i=1}^{4^m} Q_i \otimes Q_i, 
\end{equation}
where $P_l$ is the $n$ qubit Pauli string and $Q_m$ is the $m$ qubit Pauli string.

Does the following equality hold?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{4^l} P_i \otimes P_i \otimes \sum_{i=1}^{4^m} Q_i \otimes Q_i = \sum_{i=1}^{4^{l+m}} O_i \otimes O_i,
\end{equation}
where $O_i$ is the $l+m$ qubit Pauli string.

Would the summation be the same although the elements of the summation are different? In fact, they should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't hold. You can consider the simple example where $l=1$ and $m=1$ as a counter-example.

$$\sum_i P_i \otimes P_i = II + XX + YY + ZZ$$
$$\sum_i Q_i \otimes Q_i = II + XX + YY + ZZ$$

Then,

\begin{align}
\sum_i P_i \otimes P_i \sum_i Q_i \otimes Q_i &= IIII + IIXX + IIYY + IIZZ \\
&+ XXII + XXXX + XXYY + XXZZ \\
&+ YYII + YYXX + YYYY + YYZZ \\
&+ ZZII + ZZXX + ZZYY + ZZZZ \\
&\neq \sum_i O_i \otimes O_i
\end{align}

What you have in the RHS are $4^{l+m}$ Pauli strings of a set of $4^{2(l+m)}$ elements, since they are defined as $O_i \otimes O_i$, then their length is $2(l+m)$. Notice that these Pauli strings are symmetric with respect to the middle. However, from the LHS you don't have this symmetry.

Comment: Would the summation be the same although the elements of the summation are different?

Comment: @Michael.Andy notice what happens when you swap the second and third paulis in each string - i think that answers your question.